# Is it possible to show mercy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I accept a Yield?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35219/how-do-i-accept-a-yield)

If you've seriously injured an attacker, is it possible to stop the combat without killing them?

I ask because I was jumped by a necromancer at one of the standing stones, and just before dying she said "Please stop!" or something along those lines. Unfortunately she was slightly on fire at the time...

Comment: "slightly on fire" :D

Comment: @Alex: It may have helped if I'd actually stopped blasting her too, but I was in my Krull-tribute happy place.